# Integration of complex function with respect to complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, complex-integration

I was given as homework to calculate the complex integral limit

$$\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} \frac {1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-iT}^{c+iT}\frac {x^s}{s^{k+1}}ds $$

where $c>0$ and $k\geq1$ is an integer.

I am not so familiar with complex integration and relevant thorems (bad course choice), so Im looking for guidance on how to approach that kind of integral.

Comment: Are you sure about the formula of the integrated function? This looks very similar to Mellin's inverse formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform#Mellin.27s_inverse_formula If $x^s$ there turns out to be $e^{sx}$ then the problem is trivial to solve.

Comment: sure about that

Comment: I'm not very comfortable with complex integrals either, but maybe this could help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform

Comment: looks pretty useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\gamma$ be the counter-clockwise semi-circular path going from $c+iT$ to $c-iT$. Along $\gamma$, $|x^s| = |e^{s\log x}| = \exp(\Re(s \log x))$ is bounded by $|x^c|$, while $|s|\geq (T-c)$, hence:
$$\lim_{T\to + \infty}\int_{\gamma}\frac{x^s}{s^{k+1}}ds = 0,$$
and the value of the starting integral is just the residue in $s=0$ of $\frac{x^s}{s^{k+1}}$, i.e.:
$$\lim_{T\to +\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-iT}^{c+iT}\frac{x^s}{s^{k+1}}ds = \frac{\log(x)^k}{k!}.$$